# Cassandra big partitions and deduplication

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE user_songs (user_id int, song text, listen_date date, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, song))
```

and need to get unique listened songs by user. But some users can generate [big partitions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningPartitionSize.html) (more 100.000 or 100 MB).

If add listen_date to partition key (split big partitions) I cannot get unique songs and need use additional deduplication on app side. Also it complicates pagination.

Maybe there is a more effective solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split big partitions to several partitions by using consistensy hashing for part of partition key:

```
CREATE TABLE songs_listenings (
    user_id int,
    song_hash int,
    song text,
    listen_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (( user_id, song_hash ), song)
);
```

`song_hash` - is a hash which is generated based on song text. To generate this hash you need to implent a Consistent hashing function in your app which will provides ability to generate some number in a specified range (max number of partition which you want to have for single user) for a specified input parameter (song text). (E.g. Guava java library provides [consistent hashing function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#consistentHash-com.google.common.hash.HashCode-int-))

For the case with multiple listenings for the same song the consistent hash will return the same number, so it will be the same partition key and you will have only one record for the same song per user.

But due to you will have multiple partitions per user you will have to perform multiple requests to get all data for an user (iterate over all possible hash values).

Answer (score 1):

I would model your data like this;

### listened_songs_by_user

user_id(partition key) | song_id (clustering key) | listen_date

### songs_by_user

user_id (partition_key) | song_id (clustering_key)

Whenever you insert a record to listened_songs_by_user table, do these after the insert

- lookup songs_by_user;
- if there is a record

  - Yes, then do nothing
  - No, add a record to songs_by_user

If you want to retrieve unique songs, then read **songs_by_user** table by user_id

> Denormalization and duplication of data is a fact of life with Cassandra. Don't be afraid of it.
>   https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling